# Conforming to Hashable protocol?

Tags: swift, struct, swift3, hashable

I'm trying to make a dictionary with the key as a struct I've created and the value as an array of Ints. However, I keep getting the error:

> Type 'DateStruct' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

I'm pretty sure I've implemented the necessary methods but for some reason it still doesn't work.

Here's my struct with the implemented protocols:

```
struct DateStruct {
    var year: Int
    var month: Int
    var day: Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return (year+month+day).hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

    static func < (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
        if (lhs.year < rhs.year) {
            return true
        } else if (lhs.year > rhs.year) {
            return false
        } else {
            if (lhs.month < rhs.month) {
                return true
            } else if (lhs.month > rhs.month) {
                return false
            } else {
                if (lhs.day < rhs.day) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please explain to me why I'm still getting the error?

Comment: You do realise that 2024 04 03 and 2024 03 04, etc would yield the same hashvalue, right?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're missing the declaration:

```
struct DateStruct: Hashable {
```

And your `==` function is wrong. You should compare the three properties.

```
static func == (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.year == rhs.year && lhs.month == rhs.month && lhs.day == rhs.day
}
```

It's possible for two different values to have the same hash value.

Comment: Thankyou! Btw, why is the `==` wrong? Wouldn't 2 dates with the same day, month, and year have the same hashValue anyways?

Comment: Of course two equal dates will have the same hash. But two dates with the same hash are not necessarily equal. Two different dates can have the same hash. That's fine. But two dates with the same hash don't have to be equal.

Comment: Well Im confused, anyways is my `return (year+month+day).hashValue` not sufficient since 2 different date's year, month, and day could add up to the same thing like 2000, 1, 2 and 2000, 2, 1?

Comment: Your implementation of `hashValue` is fine. It would be correct to simply return 42 if you wanted (but please don't). From the `Hashable` docs: *"A hash value, provided by a type’s hashValue property, is an integer that is the same for any two instances that compare equally. That is, for two instances a and b of the same type, if a == b then a.hashValue == b.hashValue. The reverse is not true: Two instances with equal hash values are not necessarily equal to each other."* That's why you need to fix your `==` function.

Comment: Oh I see, so the combination of the `hashValue` and `==` makes comparing work. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. `==` makes comparing work. You can have comparison without hashing. `hashValue` makes values "hashable" which allows them to be used as dictionary keys or to be stored in some other form of a hash map/table. Note that `Hashable` extends `Equatable`. This means that hashing depends on comparing but comparing does not depend on hashing. Read the docs for those two protocols for further details.

Comment: Oh, so thats why if I say `dict[DateStruct1] = 1` and `dict[DateStruct2] = 2` it wouldn't be accessing the same dictionary entry even if `DateStruct1` and `DateStruct2` might have the same hashValue, it would also compare them using `==`.

Answer (score 18):

While

```
    var hashValue: Int
```

is still applicable in the legacy NSObject inheritance trees it's  otherwise obsolete.

```
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
    {
        hasher.combine(year);
        hasher.combine(month) 
    ...
```

is the swiftlely modern way to hash your way in class.

And per rmaddy answer above "==" operator also has to have kinks ironed out to be correct for your semantics.

Per Manish you get Hashable comformance for structs for free just declaring that.

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach over e.g. @rmaddy's accepted answer from three years ago? Under what conditions might someone prefer your suggestion?

Comment: This is not a question of a benefit: maddy answer is required but not sufficient to satisfy Hashable requirements. Once you add == the error remains but xcode 11.3 through 11.5 would NOT offer you to create protocol stub for hash(into

Comment: Swift will generate a hash(into:) method automatically if the struct conforms to the Hashable protocol and all properties also conform to the Hashable protocol (Swift 5.4 and Xcode 13.2.1)

Comment: Right, but structs tend to end up as classes later on :^)

Answer (score 9):

If the class has fields of type (another class), that class should adopt Hashable.

example

```
struct Project : Hashable {
    var activities: [Activity]?

}
```

Here, Activity class must adopt Hashable too.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the hashValue, you can combine the hash of your values with the `hash(into:)` method.

For more information see the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118328/1261547

Answer (score 3):

For simple structs, where all its properties are already `Hashable` (i.e. `Int`, `String`, ... ), we can conform to `Hashable` just declaring it (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable )

So no need to implement `hashValue` (which btw is deprecated) nor `==` (because `Hashable` conforms to `Equatable`).

And since we're implementing the `<` operator, then it'd make sense to conform to `Comparable`, so we can sort (i.e. `[dateStructA, dateStructB, ...].sorted()`).

So I'd do it like:

```
struct DateStruct: Comparable & Hashable {
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int

    static func < (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
        if lhs.year != rhs.year {
           return lhs.year < rhs.year
        } else if lhs.month != rhs.month {
           return lhs.month < rhs.month
        } else {
           return lhs.day < rhs.day
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified the Hashable protocol when defining struct:

`struct DateStruct: Hashable { ...`

The following code is from your example and it runs on a Playground. Please note that **your == operator has been modified here**:

```
import Foundation

struct DateStruct: Hashable {
    var year: Int
    var month: Int
    var day: Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return (year+month+day).hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.year == rhs.year && lhs.month == rhs.month && lhs.day == rhs.day
    }

    static func < (lhs: DateStruct, rhs: DateStruct) -> Bool {
        if (lhs.year < rhs.year) {
            return true
        } else if (lhs.year > rhs.year) {
            return false
        } else {
            if (lhs.month < rhs.month) {
                return true
            } else if (lhs.month > rhs.month) {
                return false
            } else {
                if (lhs.day < rhs.day) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var d0 = DateStruct(year: 2017, month: 2, day: 21)
var d1 = DateStruct(year: 2017, month: 2, day: 21)

var dates = [DateStruct:Int]()
dates[d0] = 23
dates[d1] = 49

print(dates)

print(d0 == d1) // true

d0.year = 2018

print(d0 == d1) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct HistoryFilePair : Hashable {
    //this
    public static func == (lhs: HistoryFilePair, rhs: HistoryFilePair) -> Bool {
        lhs.commit.oidShort == rhs.commit.oidShort
    }
    
    // this
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(self.commit.oidShort)
    }

    //some code of your struct/class
}
```